# send uploaded file from first form to second form (No upload again)

Tags: php, html, upload

I want to get a file from a form in index.php,Then I send that file to another form in a second page (upload1.php)
And again send to third page (with extra data in second form).

Please view This example to underestand my means better.

index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload1.php">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I send file to this form:

and second file:(upload1.php)

This is problem:how can I send file to this form without double upload?
I know this form is wrong...But I do not know how can I fixed it.

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="<?php echo $_FILES["file"]?>">
</div>
<input type="text" name="name" value="name of file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and third file to print and store the results:(upload2.php)

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

====================================================================

EDIT:

I tried do it via session but The file couldn't be store in upload folder!
index:php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload1.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload1.php

```
<?php session_start();

echo "<br>".$_SESSION['tmp_name']=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['error']=$_FILES["file"]["error"];
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['name']=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['type']=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['size']=$_FILES["file"]["size"];


?>
<form action="upload2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name" value="name of file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and upload2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " .$_SESSION['error'] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_SESSION['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_SESSION['type'] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_SESSION['size'] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_SESSION['tmp_name'] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_SESSION['name'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['name'] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['tmp_name'],
      "upload/" . $_SESSION['name']);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_SESSION['name'];
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the file location of the uploaded file or the file contents itself in a session variable. You will need to initialize the session within each successive PHP script in which it needs to be accessed. However, looking at your script I don't see any reason why it needs to be spread across multiple pages. You could combine the first 2 scripts into 1 form, and then use your last script as the form handler. This would alleviate any need for maintaining state through a session.

Comment: According to file uploaded type...I want to define metadata (custom inputs) in second form for that file...So I have to define 3 form. (I dont want use jquery)

Comment: ah i see. in that case store the file location ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) in a session variable, you can remove the hidden input filed in step 2, and then in the last page where you reference the $_FILES array you will want to reference the $_SESSION array instead. Something like $_SESSION['file_tmp_name'] or whatever you decide to call it.